# Positive definite matrices diagonalised by orthogonal matrices that are also involutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, involutions, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix. Then, $A$ is diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $P$.

I want to know when this matrix is also an involution, i.e., $P^2 = I$.

If there is any characterization of such $A$, please kindly share. Thank you.

Comment: Geometrically, this occurs precisely when there is a reflection (through some subspace) taking the eigenspaces of A to coordinate-subspaces.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the $P$ is the question has to be symmetric as it is orthogonal and involution. That much only I can understand. If you have further insight please share with me.

Comment: @James But can you say anything more algebraically which would be help me more?

Comment: It's better to start with a positive definite diagonal matrix $B.$ Then for any orthogonal involution $Q,$ you see that $A = QBQ$ is still a positive definite matrix, and $QAQ = B,$ so that $A$ is a positive definite matrix diagonalized by the orthogonal involution $Q.$ Conversely, every positive definite matrix $A$ which may be diagonalized by an orthogonal involution $P$ has such a form, since $PAP$ is positive definite diagonal, and is inverted by the orthogonal involution $P.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n \times n$ matrix $\rm A$ be symmetric and positive definite. Since $\rm A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable. Hence, there exists a (non-singular) matrix $\rm P$ such that $\mathrm A = \mathrm P \,\mbox{diag} (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n) \,\mathrm P^{-1}$, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n > 0$. Suppose $\rm P$ is orthogonal and involutory — and, thus, symmetric. Hence,

$$\mathrm A = \mathrm P \,\mbox{diag} (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n) \,\mathrm P$$

Since $\rm P$ is symmetric and involutory, it has a spectral decomposition and its eigenvalues are $\pm 1$

$$\mathrm P = \mathrm V \,\mbox{diag} (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n) \,\mathrm V^\top$$

where $\mathrm V$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n = \pm 1$.  Thus, we have the parameterization

$$\mathrm A = \mathrm V \,\mbox{diag} (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n) \,\mathrm V^\top \,\mbox{diag} (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n) \,\mathrm V \,\mbox{diag} (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n) \,\mathrm V^\top$$